# Why is the event getting fired twice when using an Event Receiver project from Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am able to fire an Event using an Event receiver which I created using Visual Studio 2010 on a custom list. But instead of firing once, it fires **twice**. I tried to debug the code and I saw that the ItemAdded event was getting executed **twice**. Is there any particular reason that this is executing in such a manner?

Comment: Is the code in the event receiver editing the event?  If so, you may need to disable event firing when you do any updates so that this doesn't happen.

Comment: @Servy Nope.. I am not editing the event.. Just changing the permissions of the list item when the Item is Added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alas!! I found it!!! I had left the elements file for the Event Receiver there, and therefore when the feature was activated for the project, the receiver got associated to ALL custom lists on the site. And in the Feature Activated event, I was stapling the event to the particular custom list. So, in effect, the Event receiver was getting attached to my particular custom list **twice**, ie, from the elements file & feature activated event. So, i just deleted the elements file of the event  reveicer and it **WORKED**!!!

Thanks all for your suggestions...

Answer (score 1):

You should check if your itemAdded event handler has not been registered twice. If yes, then deactivate the feature and delete the duplicate receiver.

You can use SharePoint Manager 2010 from codeplex to figure out how many event handlers are attached to your list

It might also be related to your versioning / requirement of checking out the file within the library : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/939307 this was for 2007 but still the case in 2010

Regards

Comment: yes.. I have checked the SP Manager 2010 and it says its registered twice. So, I tried deactivating the feature. Then, created a new feature and event receiver from scratch and deployed it. Still, it was getting registered twice instead of once. I am trying to deploy this feature to a particular custom list and not all Custom Lists in my site.

Comment: So the issue was related to your event being registered twice. There are some handy utilities on codeplex to manage event receiver and thus delete the uneeded ones.

Hope it helped